# How to sync netbeans config/plugin/updates across multiple systems?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.5

I use netbeans in both my desktop and my laptop. Updating and installing plugins on both systems is cumbersome, hence, it would be nice if there was a way to sync configurations, plugins, and updates across the systems.

I tried copying the ~/.netbeans directory, however, that also brings along the list of recent files and open projects in the other system.

Note: The OS, in both the machines, is Linux.

Comment: no, but i just copied the plugins directory. seems like there isn't a better solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some possibilities

- create your own linux package and manage the updates
- check in subversion/cvs/git whatever your vcs is
- or use a simple ftp/sftp solution